# TCP client in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to java scripting, hence need help. I am looking for a tcp client code written in java script that constantly reads data from a server socket and prints to the console. Any help is highly appreciated.thanks

Comment: Some browsers have a TCP API but its only available for use within Extensions.  You would need Flash/Java to do this, or use WebSockets to access a proxy layer.

Answer (score 0):

What environment is the Javascript client?

If it's in a browser, you can't do it, there's no support for generic TCP sockets in browsers.

However you might be able to use a `WebSocket` if you're using a newer browser that supports them.

Comment: : I am using untiy3d to run the client, server is using nodejs